# Chrome geolocation in iran

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-chrome, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

I'm using simple javascript code to get the user lcoation :

```
function getLocation() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
  } else {
    x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
  }
}
```

But because of the boycott of `Google APIs` in iran , we can't access geolocation from the chrome browser(Mozilla Browser is ok and the mobile apps has no issues because use the mobile gps) and as far as i know get user location from the ip address is not a good idea because its return the user isp location.

Is there any solution for this? for example can i use proxy before getting the location?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the research I did , there is no way to do that you can just use the databases that have latitude and longitude .
And get the province , city , district and show the approximate location to user.
Its not the best idea but at least is an idea.

I prepared [iran-provinces-cities-neighbourhoods-geo](https://github.com/Meti27/iran-provinces-cities-neighbourhoods-geo) database in for mysql and you can use it :).